# Is the end of New Super Mario Bros Wii really the end?

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-wii

I **finally** did it, I just got all the star coins in World 9 of **New Super Mario Brothers** for the Nintendo Wii! (*Wow* was level 9-7 *hard!!!*)

The game said something like "Congratulations, you've done everything there is to do!"... But knowing Nintendo, I am skeptical. **Without spoiling it**, is there anything left for me to do, or have I really maxed out the game? (If there is some hidden thing to do, a hint would be much more appreciated than a direct explanation of what the hidden thing is)

FYI, My save game icon does have 5 stars on it.

Comment: Now you hack the game!!

Comment: @badp: AWESOME!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. 5 stars is the maximum. You've really done everything! Congratulations!

Technically, I suppose you could go and buy all the videos now, but you don't get anything from viewing them all.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The only thing I get from viewing the Super Skills videos is awe, LOL.

Answer (score 9):

Well, there is *one* thing.  You can make the stars on your save file sparkle by never having a Super Guide *appear* (the green box that rings like a doorbell if you fail to pass a level within 8 attemps).  Just not using one doesn't count.

Once *even one* appears, I believe to earn the sparkly stars you have to start over from the last point you saved, so that the Super Guide appearing isn't part of your save file.

I would probably beat the game as fast as possible.  Once you've beaten Bowser, you're able to save your game at any point, not just when you've finished a castle or taken a cannon.  This should make restarting a level if the Super Guide appears much less time consuming.

Comment: Never having it *appear* or never using it?

Comment: Never having it *appear*.